# How to rotate a figure in all directions in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to rotate a figure horizontally in python. With the mouse I am only able to rotate through one degree of freedom as well as being able to spin the figure, for example this is what I can do at the momement:

[image]

These movements are only vertical. I would like to be able to rotate the figure in all directions, for example:

[image]

This would allow me to put the figure on its side etc. However at the moment I cannot do this, all I can do it rotate along one degree of freedom.

Here is my code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
import numpy as np
import math

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

nphi,nz= 13, 101
r=1
phi = np.linspace(0,360, nphi)/180.0*np.pi
z= np.linspace(0,350,nz)

cols=[]
verts2 = []
for i  in range(len(phi)-1):
    cp0= r*np.cos(phi[i])
    cp1= r*np.cos(phi[i+1])
    sp0= r*np.sin(phi[i])
    sp1= r*np.sin(phi[i+1])

    for j in range(len(z)-1):
        z0=z[j]
        z1=z[j+1]
        verts=[]
        verts.append((cp0, sp0, z0))
        verts.append((cp1, sp1, z0))
        verts.append((cp1, sp1, z1))
        verts.append((cp0, sp0, z1))
        verts2.append(verts)

        col=plt.cm.Blues(0.4)
        cols.append(col)

poly3 = Poly3DCollection(verts2, facecolor=cols ,edgecolor = "red" )  
poly3.set_alpha(0.5)

ax.add_collection3d(poly3)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_xlim3d(-3, 3)
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_ylim3d(-3, 3)
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_zlim3d(0, 300)

plt.axis('off')
ax.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think you can; From the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.3/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.view_init):

> ‘elev’ stores the elevation angle in the z plane. ‘azim’ stores the
>   azimuth angle in the x,y plane

So you've not actually got 3 degrees of freedom here, because you can only rotate in the xy *plane*, rather than around each axis independently.

It's a bit clearer if you display the axes:

[image]